# How to get only one value for the mode after group by?

Tags: python, pandas, list, group-by, mode

I am trying to calculate the mode value of a column after grouping my dataset. However there is often a tie in the mode and I get multiple result as a list (eg. [2,3,4])

Is it possible to only access the highest value in this list?

My output looks like this:

```
user  session   mode_score
98    1         5
      2         4
      3         5
      4         5
      5        [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

However I would like it to look like this:

```
user  session   mode_score
 98   1         5
      2         4
      3         5
      4         5
      5         5
```

I used this code to get to the mode:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df[['user', 'session', 'audio_score']].groupby(['user','session'])['audio_score'].agg(pd.Series.mode))
```

Comment: You could try using `[-1]` to access the last element of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = (df[['user', 'session', 'audio_score']]
       .groupby(['user','session'])['audio_score']
       .agg(lambda x: x.mode().max())
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose we have the following dataframe :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {'mode_score': [5,4,5,5, [1,2,3,4,5]],} )

        mode_score
0                5
1                4
2                5
3                5
4  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

```py
df.agg({'mode_score': lambda x: max(x) if type(x)==list else x})
#    mode_score
# 0           5
# 1           4
# 2           5
# 3           5
# 4           5
```